# Date comparison failed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I try to compare to date. I It works successfully on development mode, but the production has behaviour different.

```
object_date.to_date <= Date.today
```

The prompt of two date : 2014-04-02T00:00:00+0000 vs 2014-01-15T00:00:00+0000

And the code raises `failed with ArgumentError: comparison of Date with Time failed`

This code was executed in delayedjob.

I don't understand why the comparison failed.

Comment: Where are you calling this from?

Comment: In the loop on array of objects. Nothing crazy

Comment: In controller or model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to_date will return self, so I think for some reason object_time is a Time-object rather than a Date-object. If changing the type of object_time is not acceptable, you will have to parse the time first using the parse method in Date.

Try if `Date.parse(object_date.to_date.to_s) <= Date.today` will do the job.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i try with `Date.parse or to_datetime` and its works.